# Rotate Overlay in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

Is there any way to rotate the `Overlay` component in `react-native-maps` ?
I tried to use the `bearing` prop. But it seems the prop is not available. Tried to rotate using the `style` prop as well. It didn't work either

```
<Overlay
            image={IMAGE_URL}
            style={{transform: [{ rotate: '90 deg' }]}}   // not working
            bearing={VALUE}  // not working
            bounds={BOUNDS}
            location={LOCATION}
            anchor={[0.5, 0.5]}
            width={WIDTH}
            height={WIDTH}
          />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Install the `react-native-maps` library from the master branch. In the master branch, `Overlay` component has the `bearing` prop. Use the below command

`npm install https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps.git#master --save`